# Unable to access element.scrollLeft position from Vue Computed property ? how?

Tags: vue.js

I am unable to access the scrollLeft value of a window from within Vue. I have tried using a method and computed property. I have also tried accessing directly and via Refs please see the fiddle below.

```
let el  = document.getElementsByClassName("myContainer")
          if (el != null) {
            return el.scrollLeft
        } else {
         return 'unknown'
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oj1bu5nt/

Answer (score 1):

When we get elements using the document we need to use the 0th index to access the element.

Update your if condition as:

```
if (el[0] != null) {
    return el[0].scrollLeft
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and you are absolutely right. However this does still not resolve the issue as the computed property should return the new value when the scroll position changes which it does not. Also this does not explain why $refs does not work. Please see updated fiddle below. https://jsfiddle.net/oj1bu5nt/1/

Comment: I am able to obtain the value i need by attaching an event on scroll and then assigning this to a data.value . However i am still curious as to why this would not work.  Working Link >> https://jsfiddle.net/c7zvj6an/

Answer (score 1):

Using computed with `$ref` in this case won't work because...

As said here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/watching-refs-item-for-change-in-clientheight/60039/2 where your issue is directly related...

> Vue is only reactive to its own data, it cannot react to DOM element
> property changes.

So watch nor computed property will work here. What you can do is to listen to scroll event and assign the value to variable, like such:

```
<div ref="myContainer" .... v-on:scroll="getScroll()">
```

And the function:

```
getScroll() {
  this.scroll = this.$refs.myContainer.scrollLeft;
}
```

where you of course have a data variable named `scroll`.

**Your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AJT82/5pf0joac/1/)**

Or then you can go by the other answer provided :)